# Exibir imagens dinâmica utilizando Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Olá, estou com dificuldade em exibir imagens dinâmicas utilizando sintax Razor, em um projeto asp.net MVC 5.

Tenho o caminho da imagem guardado em uma coluna na base de dados, de nome **Imagem**.

Abaixo o código da minha view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { 
<div class="item branding">
   <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.imagem)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
       <div class="works-overlay">
           <div class="wo-inner">
                <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)</h4>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
}
```

Porém quando a view é renderizada, o src da imagem fica correto, da maneira que está salvo na base de dados:
**~/Content/images/galeria/minha-imagem-123.jpg**. Porem o caminho da imagem completo está incorreto, como exibido abaixo:

```
http://localhost:9474/Albuns/~/Content/images/galeria/minha-imagem-123.jpg
```

Abaixo segue meu controller, com um método de listagem simples.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.portifolio.ToList());
        }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar em como eu faço para exibir corretamente as imagens? A ideia é armazenar no banco o caminho da imagem no servidor, após upload da mesma. E na hora de renderizar, apenas pegar o caminho da imagem.

Caso alguém tenha uma opinião melhor de armazenar/exibir imagens, por favor, pode comentar.

Comment: Aparentemente o seu Model está concatenando a sua página atual com a string do banco (que no caso é o path da image). Quem está formatando a url? Seria o Controller ou o Model (acredito que o seu Model apenas use `get; set;`)?

Comment: Sim, meu Model está apenas usando get; set;

Comment: Tem como adicionar o método que você está usando para concatenar a sua questão?

Comment: Erico, em meu projeto eu faço da seguinte maneira: no atributo `src` da tag `image` eu ponho assim e funciona, por exemplo: *src="@Model.Foto"* e dessa forma eu consigo pegar a foto no meu projeto e exibi-la.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento adicionei o método da action result. É uma listagem simples, onde pego os registro da base de dados, e uma delas é o caminho da imagem no servidor.

Comment: Mas este é o método que está causando o problema?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento basicamente o problema é que eu não consigo exibir minhas imagens. Eu costumo armazenar o caminho da mesma no banco. Utilizava assim no webforms, e na tag src utilizava src='<%# Eval("imagem")%>'... porem no mvc não obtive sucesso em pensar da mesma maneira.

Comment: Quando eu digo método me refiro a função do controller, essa função index é a que você usa para concatenar o path com /albuns/

Comment: Não concatena, tenho armazenado na base de dados o caminho da imagem "~/Content/images/galeria/minha-imagem-123.jpg"

Comment: Eu entendi @EricoSouza, é que por você estar usando MVC acredito que todos nós pensamos que as imagens trabalhavam com "rotas", mas após ver o "update" da sua questão e o seu comentário, acredito que o caminho exibido no `src` seja "estático". Veja a minha resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta é a maneira incorreta de devolver uma imagem para o HTML, visto que você está expondo uma parte da sua infraestrutura no código.

O correto é você fazer uma `Action` apenas para devolver a imagem, mais ou menos assim:

```
    public FileResult Image(int id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            var imagem = _db.Imagens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ImagemId == id);
            if (imagem != null)
            {
                var imageFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/galeria/" + imagem.imagem);
                return File(imageFile, "image/jpeg");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Uso:

```
<img src="~/Imagens/Image/5" alt="@item.nome" />
```

Pode até parecer mais trabalhoso, mas em termos de desempenho, é quase a mesma coisa e te garante segurança estrutural.

Comment: Certo, estou apenas um pouco confuso, essa "action", eu crio no meu controller? E como eu faço para controlar certinho a imagem de cada registro, sendo que minha action Index, tenho apenas um: return View(db.portifolio.ToList()); ?

Comment: Sim, cria a Action no Controller. O controle está no `foreach`, em que você manda o Id para a Action de imagem no Controller.

Comment: Quando eu utilizava projetos webforms, eu costumava armazenar o caminho completo onde a imagem é salva no servidor. Utilizando asp.net mvc, eu não preciso fazer isso, pelo action que escreveu como exemplo, posso simplesmente armazenar o nome da mesma, e criar a rota das imagens... correto?

Comment: Depois de algumas tentativas e um bom entendimento, deu tudo certo e funcionou corretamente dessa maneira. Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez vlw

Answer (score 1):

Após ler o seu comentário na resposta do @CiganoMorrisonMendez, percebi que você não está usando "rotas" nas imagens, então vou supor que as imagens mostram este caminho `http://localhost:9474/Albuns/~/Content/images/galeria/minha-imagem-123.jpg` quando você está acessando o endereço `http://localhost:9474/Albuns/` e que o caminho `~/Content/images/galeria/minha-imagem-123.jpg` é estático.

Isso quer dizer que você está usando caminho *relativo* quando deveria usar *absoluto*, você pode modificar o seu `view`, ao invés de usar assim:

```
<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.imagem)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```

Use desta maneira:

```
<img src="/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.imagem)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```

(Eu tenho pouco conhecimento de "asp.net mvc", por isto não posso afirmar a maneira correta de usar o `src`)

O código inteiro deve ficar assim:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { 
<div class="item branding">
   <img src="/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.imagem)" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
       <div class="works-overlay">
           <div class="wo-inner">
                <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)</h4>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema. O problema é a exposição do diretório `Content`, que é estático e não manipulado por rotas, possibilitando ataques e acessos indevidos.

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, mas é justamente por isto que eu até comentei que *não havia* entendido o problema, pois pensei que realmente ele estava usando "rotas" e concordo com a sua resposta, porém eu aqui apenas respondi aonde está a falha dele, devido ao meu baixo conhecimento de "asp.net mvc", não posso formular "dicas", apenas indicar a falha.

Comment: Galera, me desculpa se eu ainda estou um pouco confuso. Conforme a resposta do @CiganoMorrisonMendez e os comentários do Guilherme, enfim o problema é que eu quis utilizar uma técnica parecida com a que eu utilizava quando uso webforms, porem agora estou começando a entender que eu devia utilizar "rotas" nas imagens, o que é uma maneira melhor de exibir as imagens de meus registros.... certo?

Comment: @EricoSouza não sei em questão de "segurança", mas em questão de criar "url canonical" e até mesmo reduzir o tamanho do "path" visivel ao cliente, com certeza eu concordo com o uso de "rotas". No caso o Cigano disse para fazer o "trabalho" de tratamento no "for" dentro do "View", porém eu acredito que talvez você possa fazer isto no "Controller" em um método isolado e reaproveitar este método para outros "locais", mas se vai usar apenas neste View, então acho que você pode trabalhar perfeitamente dentro do próprio View. Claro isto é apenas a minha opinião.