# asp.net servindo arquivos estaticos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação em mvc3 (asp.net 4.0, dotnet 4.0), 
rodando em iis8 (mas também está rodando no iis 7 e iis 7.5).

Dentro da aplicação tenho uma pasta chamada `/dados`,
exemplo `localhost/minhaapp/dados`.

Meus clientes salvam arquivos HTML dentro dessa pasta,
e esses arquivos HTML são acessados pelo sistema feito em mvc3.

Mas os usuários estão acessando os arquivos diretamente pela URL do browser,
exemplo `localhost/minhaapp/dados/relatorio1.html`, ao invés
de acessar por uma opção interna do sistema feito em mvc3.

- Tem como bloquear o acesso via método GET dos arquivos HTML da pasta `/dados`?

Mas quero que o sistema feito em mvc3 consiga acessar esses arquivos via
método POST.
Esse não é o método mais seguro, deve existir muitas outras possibilidade,
mas se conseguir isso já estaria ótimo.

Tentei várias formas, rewrite, módulos, urlmapping, mvc controler, etc,
mas nenhuma dessas formas captura o requisição do browser para arquivos estáticos.
Sei que arquivo estáticos são servidos diretamente pelo iis.

- Mas tem alguma forma do asp.net intercetar requisições de arquivos estático?
- Se não for possível via asp.net, tem alguma configuração que funcione nos
  iss 8, 7.5 r 7?

Não posso alterar para outra pasta, nem salvar os arquivos de outra forma, ou seja,
por questões internas (políticas internas, fato de já ser assim e muito difundido e
usados por vários clientes), a forma e o local como os arquivos são salvos,
NÃO pode ser alterado.

Comment: Uma dica que talvez possa ajudar: Salvar o arquivo com o nome criptografado (Ex: de "arquivo.html" para "123asd.html"). Sendo assim quando o usuário tentasse forçar o acesso o mesmo não iria conseguir visto que não ia encontrar arquivo utilizando o nome real.

Comment: Também pensei nisso, mas o arquivo é salvo via Excel pelo usuário, então teria que criar um serviço para monitorar o diretório, e ficar renomeando. Espero que exista outra forma, senão terei que fazer isso.

Answer (score 3):

Você informa ao ISS que toda requisição deve passar por ele. O IIS não aplica permissão sobre arquivos estáticos.

Em seu `Web.config` coloque o seguinte código:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sim já tentei isso, mas mesmo assim, as requisições de arquivos estáticos não chega na app. Tentei com global.asax e criando um módulo, em nenhum deles, a requisição chegou no BeginRequest. OBS: O IIS obriga a usar um POOL em modo Classic. Tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui fazer funcionar, coloquei runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true", alterei o pool da aplicação para o modo integrado, e coloquei o método BegingRequest no global.asax, reiniciei a aplicação, e agora está captura todas as requisições.

Answer (score 1):

[Conforme já respondi aqui, esta é a maneira **incorreta** de disponibilizar arquivos estáticos na sua aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45358/exibir-imagens-din%C3%A2mica-utilizando-razor/45367#45367).

## Tem como bloquear o acesso via método GET dos arquivos HTML da pasta /dados?

Sim, criando no seu *Controller* um método *Index* para prevenir o acesso à raiz, ou então um arquivo `index.html` vazio.

## Mas tem alguma forma do asp.net intercetar (sic) requisições de arquivos estático (sic)?

Tem. Você só precisa fazer um método no seu *Controller* que devolva um [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Adicionalmente, é bom definir uma rota que sempre redirecione para `Index`, no caso de seu usuário tentar acessar o arquivo diretamente:

## App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dados",
            url: "dados/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dados", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Sim entendo que não é a maneira correta, mas isso não está no meu controle infelizmente, e o que você sugeriu não revolve o problema na situação atual, infelizmente. Não existe nenhuma forma do asp.net/mvc3 interceptar requisições de arquivos estáticos?

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net Resolve sim. `FileResult` devolve qualquer arquivo em qualquer diretório passível de ser mapeado pelo servidor. Qualquer coisa diferente disso é expôr indevidamente a topologia de diretórios da sua aplicação.

Comment: Hum, acho que entendi o que você respondeu. Fiz conforme suas sugestões, mas continua permitindo acessar os arquivos no localhost/Dados/Relatorio1.html. Não posso alterar a situação atual, onde certo usuários salvam arquivos estátivos (html) na pasta dados do sistema, que "deveriam" ser acessados internamente pelo sistema, e não manualmente pelo usuário.

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net Neste caso ainda é preciso configurar uma rota especial para redirecionar a requisição sempre para o método `Index` do seu *Controller*. Vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Isso tudo funciona conforme você comentou, criei uma aplicação mvc3 nova para fazer os testes. Mas deixa de funcionar quando é criado o diretório "Dados". Se tem apenas o controller dados, ok, mas depois de criar o diretório volta a permitir acessar o arquivo, além de não funcionar mais a rota especial criada. Você já chegou a testa nessas situações?

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net Sim, de fato tinha um erro. Veja agora.

Comment: Testei sua correção mas o comportamento continua o mesmo. Alguma outra sugestão? Estava lendo o pipeline/cycle do asp.net, e não consegui encontrar uma forma de fazer.