# Mostrar uma imagem em mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Tenho a seguinte *controller* para cadastrar uma imagem e alguns campos, sendo que a propriedade da imagem é `string`:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Cadastrar(NoticiaViewModel vm, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                vm.ComboCategoriaId = new CategoriaRepositorio().BuscarTodos().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.NomeCategoria, Value = Convert.ToString(x.CategoriaId) });
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(vm);
                }
                var mapper = Mapper.Map<NoticiaViewModel, Noticia>(vm);
                _repositorio.Salvar(mapper);
                if (file != null)
                {
                    String[] strName = file.FileName.Split('.');
                    String strExt = strName[strName.Count() - 1];
                    string pathSave = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}", Server.MapPath("~/Imagem/noticias/"), mapper.NoticiaId, strExt);
                    String pathBase = String.Format("/Imagem/noticias/{0}.{1}", mapper.NoticiaId, strExt);
                    file.SaveAs(pathSave);
                    mapper.Imagem = pathSave;
                    _repositorio.Atualizar(mapper);
                }

                TempData["mensagem"] = "Noticia cadastrada com sucesso";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Até ai tudo bem, eu gravo o caminho onde minha imagem está.
O problema é pra mostrar ela:

```
        public ActionResult Visualizar(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                Noticia noticia = _repositorio.BuscarPorId(id);
                if (noticia == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                var mapper = Mapper.Map<Noticia, NoticiaViewModel>(noticia);
                return View(mapper);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Eu tô usando isso para trazer do banco os dados de uma determinada notícia:

A `View` está assim:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <small class="text-right">@Model.DataCadastro</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3 class="text-left">Categoria: <b>@Model.Categoria.NomeCategoria</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h2 class="text-center">Título: @Model.Titulo</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Descricao)
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <img src="@Model.Imagem" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mas a imagem não aparece.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Sua imagem está salvo no banco de dados ? Se sim, em qual tipo de dados ?

Comment: Não, to salvando apenas o caminho dela, a imagem está dentro da pasta Imagem/noticias

Comment: Veja esse exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45358/exibir-imagens-din%C3%A2mica-utilizando-razor?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Verifica o caminho que é colocado na tag `<img>`

Comment: o caminha da minha imagem está certo que é este
<img src="c:\users\usuario\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\IESB\IESB.Apresentacao\Imagem\noticias\3.jpg" >
ela so não aparece

Comment: o caminho da imagem tem de ser relativo e não absoluto

Answer (score 1):

Olá, no seu código troque o seguinte trecho:

```
   mapper.Imagem = pathSave;
```

para:

```
   mapper.Imagem = pathBase;
```

O que basicamente vocè está fazendo é salvar o caminho físico de sua imagem, e não a url a ser exibida. Você sempre poderá obter o caminho físico da imagem através do método MapPaht como fez em seu código, então não há problemas em salvar a Url.

Comment: Os dois códigos me parecem iguais. Qual a diferença?

Comment: No código original a propriedade Imagem de mapper , a qual é utilizada para armazenar a url da imagem a ser exibida na página na tag img, está sendo atribuida com o valor de **pathSave** a qual é convertida no caminho físico a partir de Server.MapPath.

Em minha alteração atribuo a propriedade Imagem o valor de **pathBase** o qual recebe a Url relativa, e não o **caminho físico**.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Então ao gravar na base e passa a gravar o caminho relativo **"/Imagem/noticias/imagem.jpg** e não mais **C:\projetodele\Imagem\Noticias\imagem.jpg"**.

Você pode notar que é esta a causa do problema no comentário feito pelo próprio Alysson: 

"o caminha da minha imagem está certo que é este <img src="c:\users\usuario\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\IESB\IESB.Apresentacao\Imagem\noticias\3.jpg" >"

Perceba que o atributo src de img está apontando para um caminho físico. Por isso a mudança.

Comment: Sim, mas veja que seu exemplo o código do "de" e do "para" estão iguais.

Comment: O que muda é a atribuição, de (mapper.Imagem = **pathSave**;) para  (mapper.Imagem = **pathBase**;)  é esta a linha em suma que realmente existe uma mudança.

Comment: Ah, bom. Não seria melhor deixar só essa linha ao invés das quatro?

Comment: Corrigido, obrigado.